# How to correctly exit the thread blocking on mpsc::Receiver

Tags: rust, channel

```
impl A {
    fn new() -> (A, std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<Data>) {
        let (sender, receiver) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

        let objA = A { sender: sender, }; // A spawns threads, clones and uses sender etc
        (objA, receiver)
    }
}

impl B {
    fn new() -> B {
        let (objA, receiver) = A::new();

        B {
            a: objA,
            join_handle: Some(std::thread::spwan(move || {
                loop {
                    match receiver.recv() {
                        Ok(data) => /* Do Something, inform main thread etc */,
                        Err(_) => break,
                    }
                }
            })),
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for B {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // Want to do something like "sender.close()/receiver.close()" etc so that the following
        // thread joins. But there is no such function. How do i break the following thread ?
        self.join_handle().take().unwrap().join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to cleanly exit under such a circumstance ? The thing is that when either receiver or sender is dropped the other sniffs this and gives an error. In case of `receiver` it will be woken up and will yield an error in which case i am breaking out of the infinite and blocking loop above. However how do i do that explicitly using this very property of channels, without resorting to other flags in conjunction with `try_recv()`etc., and cleanly exit my thread deterministically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not sending a specific message to shut this thread? I do not know what is your data but most of the time it may be an enum and adding a enum variant like 'MyData::Shutdown' in your receive you can simply break out of the loop.

Comment: this is the clean solution, everything else is either a little or a lot hacky

Comment: Closing a channel to indicate the producer is done is idiomatic IMO.

Comment: true, but catching that indication through the `Err` feels wrong. Instead [`Receiver::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.iter) should be used.

Comment: seems cleanest .. went with this approach finally .. thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `a` field of your `B` type in an `Option`. This way in the `Drop::drop` method you can do `drop(self.a.take())` which will replace the field with a `None` and drop the sender. This closes the channel and your thread can now be properly joined.

Comment: hmm .. is it always intended to be this round-about ? Do you have any other way ? I'll wait for sometime before accepting an answer.

Comment: I don't see how this could be different, because `Drop::drop` takes a `&mut self`, which you cannot move out of.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new channel and swap your actual sender out with the dummy-sender. Then you can drop your sender and therefor join the thread:

```
impl Drop for B {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let (s, _) = channel();
        drop(replace(&mut self.a.sender, s));
        self.join_handle.take().unwrap().join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Try it out in the playpen: http://is.gd/y7A9L0

I don't know what the overhead of creating and immediately dropping a channel is, but it's not free and unlikely to be optimized out (There's an `Arc` in there).

---

on a side-note, Your infinite loop with a match on `receiver.recv()` could be replaced by a for loop using the [`Receiver::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.iter) method:

```
for _ in receiver.iter() {
    // do something with the value
}
```